# TypeScript generics work when you call it but not in the function body?

Tags: typescript

Say I have this example:

```js
type Keys = 'one' | 'two';
type Values<T extends Keys> = T extends 'one' 
  ? { id: 1, name: 'hello1' } 
  : T extends 'two' 
    ? { id: 2, value: 'hello2' }
      : never;

type Fn = <T extends Keys>(key: T) => (value: Values<T>) => void;

const fn: Fn = (key) => (value) => {
  if (key === 'one') {
    const name = value.name; // This throws compile error
  }
}

// Both of these `fn` calls correctly limit the `value` argument based on the `key`
fn('one')({ id: 1, name: 'hello1' });
fn('two')({ id: 2, value: 'hello2' });
```

Can someone explain to me **why** this setup *correctly limits* the allowed types for the `value` argument when invoking the `fn` method, but doesn't allow me to narrow `value` after using a Type Guard inside the `fn` implementation?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=39&pln=15&pc=2#code/FAFwngDgpgBA0lMBnGBeGByA9gOyhmAH0xAHcsMBuUSWANQEMAbAVyiQB4AVGKADxBQcAExQJkAPjQwe-QSJTY8BYDBgB+GAG8YAS2EAuGAEYANDBwMAtlCMYAFlCZMsxggF8YqmEdkChoiTkKmpqmjr6RgBM5gBuzGx2js5YUR7eoT4WULFQAE7UNNAwAGI40ty8-grwiEgSABQA1oi+AJRoUg3xrLYwjL2cXBIdqFKxWPqFAMa4SCAwAGY4RmXSzYijXT1sW9reuoswG2BoqOhK+B1aGTCzOPMW1rDoO1AAdJY21GruwH-AZYNS4YNoNCKGEzmL59BxOFxuGDuNrUIEYMgUMEQ6JxBKw5IuNJIlHAQEsHDTEC6XAwJBYGwlcnTE52XBXIzdPFGbFQp42JLw1wePYTKZkilUml0hlMllBTEct7cvSQmIwJWYAmpYWddWTYSFRZMyXlaVQRkUuXiJDXLxqPJQEAsPLlTm9IwDNica0jXU3TKHY4tU7nC5s0H7TJqe6PGHSN6fZ4-UJ-X7-Um6HCCPKLBjTWAASTW-qDrUw4baiq52hVRjMfPxgsRyN1ooN3jl6OCleOGp5ao1cJSRJbYz1YoBMYWyxWMCL5XQJz2bt2foOR2BMIImfVeOutynDfjeMT328f3cQA) - I have this playground with a few other attempts to make this work, but not success.

Ultimately I'm trying to use something similar to this as a `useCallback` method in a React project where an `onChange` prop is set with the callback invoked with a key, then the event sends the value. Since I know the types of the event, I feel like this should be possible. Ex:

```js
<Component1 onChange={handleChange('key1')} />
<Component2 onChange={handleChange('key2')} />
```

Comment: So your question is "why doesn't this work" and not "how can I write it so that it works"?  They are separate but related questions and the one you care about most informs where someone answering should spend their time.  It doesn't work because generic types are harder for the compiler to analyze than specific types; when you *call* the function the types are specified and no longer generic. *Inside* the function the compiler has a harder time, which I could go into more detail in an answer. If you're just looking for a *fix*, then I'd spend time on that and not the explanation.

Comment: What's wrong with the `IFn` in your playground link?  (If you reply to either of my comments, please mention me via @jcalz or I won't be notified)

Comment: @jcalz The only problem with the `IFn` is that it isn't based on the `key`. If that is the only way to have this functionality then I can can go that route. Per your first comment, I suppose the thing I *care* most about is a fix, but I really wanted to know the *why* as well.

Comment: Hmm I still don’t know which one to focus on in the answer.  If you got two answers, one which provided a fix but no indication of why your original didn’t work, and one with a detailed explanation of the problem but no fix, which one would you be more likely to accept?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry I don't post questions often so I didn't know how strict the rules were. I would mark the answer that poses a fix. How should I change the question to reflect that? Thanks for the help, btw!

Comment: I don’t think the rules are necessarily that strict, I’m just trying to know how to focus a possible answer.  An actual answer would probably address both, at least somewhat.  Right now I’m afk so I’ll look into a fix when I get a chance.

Comment: The more I look at this the less I think I'll have a good fix; the underlying problem is basically the same as [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) except that you're using currying.  And the recommended approach at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) doesn't seem to work here.  There doesn't seem to be a way to express that correlation in a single call signature.

Comment: Random idea: what if you used an object type to map keys to value types? E.g. `type Values = { one: { id: 1, name: "hello1" } }`

Comment: You can do that but it doesn't solve the issue.  The closest I can get is something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wer3gN), which hides the problem by intentionally using overload function statement typechecking looseness to rephrase a generic in terms of a union of rest tuples.  See if that works for you or not; if so I can write up the answer. If not, what's wrong with it?  (Please @jcalz-mention me to reply if you want me to be notified)

Comment: @jcalz This is very interesting and I think in a general case this would be a great solution, and I have no problem accepting it as the answer. I will have to play around with it a bit more in React to see if it works there as it feels a bit cumbersome (first impression).

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.  Maybe not until tomorrow (getting late in my time zone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's dispense with your [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) definition of `Values<K>`. This can be easily refactored to an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into a mapping interface:

```
interface KeyVals {
  one: { id: 1, name: "hello1" },
  two: { id: 2, value: "hello2" }
}
type Keys = keyof KeyVals;
type Values<K extends Keys> = KeyVals[K];
```

The compiler is slightly better at analyzing indexed accesses than it at analyzing conditional types.  This doesn't fix your problem, but it does make my workaround behave better, so I'll do that.

---

The main problem here is the mismatch between how the compiler deals with [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and how it deals with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  Your `fn()` function call signature is generic, with values `k` of type `K` and `v` of type `Values<K>`, but your function implementation needs to treat these as discriminated unions, where checking the value of `k` should narrow the type of `v`.  But checking `k` only narrows the type of `k`, and does narrow the type *parameter* `K`.  So you can't treat these generic values as discriminated unions.

This is sort of a general limitation in TypeScript currently, with various issues in GitHub raised about different aspects of it.  For example, there's [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014), which explicitly asks for a check on `k` to narrow the type parameter `K`.  That issue is currently open.  It would probably also need [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) to be implemented, so that you can prevent people from passing in a *union* for `K`, since that messes things up.  There's also [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) which asks for how to treat unions generically, and the recommended fix/approach to it at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) is to essentially reframe unions as generics... but here you *need* the union behavior to work.  Right now this is just not possible, it seems.

---

You also tried the approach of making `fn()` a non-generic [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).  This would avoid generics entirely.  Unfortunately the compiler is even less able to analyze overloads than it is with generics.  Inside the implementation of an overloaded function *statement* the compiler does not constrain things to only be compatible with the call signatures; it only looks at the implementation signature, and it matches the implementation and call signatures very loosely.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235) for a declined request to have overloads checked in a type safe way.  And if you use an overloaded function *expression* then the compiler is too *strict*.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#47669](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669) for a still-open request to do something different here.  So overloads can either be made to suppress errors (but allow some unsafe things) or catch errors (but prevent some safe things) but not both.

---

So, as far as I know, there's no way to refactor your code so that the compiler allows you to do the right thing while stopping you from doing the wrong thing.  All I can think of is a workaround.

In this case, the closest I can get to useful safety is to use a function overload statement to bridge the gap between generics and discriminated unions.  It looks like this:

```
function uncurriedFn<K extends Keys>(k: K, v: Values<K>): void;
function uncurriedFn(...[k, v]: { [K in Keys]: [k: K, v: Values<K>] }[Keys]) {
  if (k === 'one') {
    const name = v.name;
  }
}
```

So `uncurriedFn()` is a single function that takes both `k` and `v` instead of the curried version that takes `k` and returns a function that takes `v`.  The *call signature* of the function is generic, so you should be able to call it safely as a generic function.  In fact, that lets you use it inside your intended curried version:

```
type Fn = <K extends Keys>(k: K) => (v: Values<K>) => void;
const fn: Fn = (k) => (v) => uncurriedFn(k, v)    

fn('one')({ id: 1, name: 'hello1' });
fn('two')({ id: 2, value: 'hello2' });
```

So that's the call signature.  What about the *implementation*?  Well, the implementation signature is non-generic and takes a [destructured discriminanted union](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) argument.  The type `{[K in Keys]: [k: K, v: Values<K>]}[Keys]` is a *distributive object* (as coined in ms/TS#47109) that evaluates to `[k: 'one', v: Values<'one'>] | [k: 'two', v: Values<'two'>]`.  This *also* only allows safe calls; it will complain if you mismatch `k` and `v`.  But now the implementation body can proceed to use `k` and `v` as a destructured discriminated union; check `k`, and `v` is narrowed.

---

And there you go.  Everything is, in fact, safe (or as safe as reasonable... generics can be used unsafely sometimes), and the compiler doesn't complain.  The trick is, again, this pair of call and implementation signatures:

```
function uncurriedFn<K extends Keys>(k: K, v: Values<K>): void;
function uncurriedFn(...[k, v]: { [K in Keys]: [k: K, v: Values<K>] }[Keys]) {}
```

In an ideal world the compiler would know that the signature `<K extends Keys>(k: K, v: Values<K>) => void` and `(...args: {[K in Keys]: [k: K, v: Values<K>]}[Keys]) => void` are compatible (modulo ms/TS#27808).  But it doesn't know this, so you have to trick it by taking advantage of the looseness of overload statement checking.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgNIQJ4DU4BsDOyA3gFDLID2IEAXMcsACZ0CMANMiHALa3IBEACwi5cFFv2QBfNmWRgA7hTpEGzZACYOANzwBXPkJFiNkqSXNgMABxToMhALzIA1pgow0mHAQDcJK1tkHwN8AB5UZAgAD0gQRkJ7fAA+ZGd7H3wAbVQAXX8SGD0QBDBgKmRihD0oKGAIRgAxEAio2Ih4xMwUgAoXOlQdOhCIcNRkgEo6bQomfyKSsoqqmrqG5p6AOm2slx1clWQchhAvBwOj-rQh4P1RiOTc6Rzu3IniOWBPPrTHZwByKgQf7vUjkcgIKj4MCcHgoZzaTZcXj+cjmSw2FDNNLIVoxOIJM69K6od6OVI9bTDO5jSZpVIzOYkSEgaHIGAgOjY5x9MkU7R8yolVb1JogPo6CYkaUcnqA6ggnqqJisDjIvj-YSicT-aQTebi-6KCiK5XqLTIXS4Ax0TXGCgaXVSfXS11AA)