# How to infer or to deduce the return type from an argument in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, return, overloading, type-inference

I have a type that is deductible from one field of the object.

And I wrote this function that takes the zoneType and returns the associate zone.

But at the end, and on each call I get : `MyType1 | MyType2 | MyType3` and not the associated type. This type is actually deductible from the argument, since the switch case can easily find the type.

We are talking about geojson btw.

I was wondering trying overloading, but typescript does not allow having duplicated functions.
Also, infer, but it looks "huge" for something that can be guessed by TS itself?

I will appreciate your help.

Thanks !

```
type MyType1 = "geojson.Feature<geojson.MultiPolygon>";
type MyType2 = "geojson.Feature<geojson.Polygon>";
type MyType3 = "geojson.FeatureCollection<geojson.Polygon>";

export type ZoneGeojson = MyType1 | MyType2 | MyType3;

type InternalZone = {
  id: number;
  zone: ZoneGeojson | null;
  zone_type: ZoneZoneType;
};

export interface Zone1 extends InternalZone {
  zone_type: ZoneZoneType.Type1 | ZoneZoneType.Type2;
  zone: MyType1 | null;
}

export interface Zone2 extends InternalZone {
  zone_type: ZoneZoneType.Type3;
  zone: MyType1 | null;
}

export interface Zone3 extends InternalZone {
  zone_type: ZoneZoneType.Type4;
  zone: MyType1 | null;
}
```

```
export const exportZone = (
  zoneType: ZoneZoneType,
  zone: FeatureCollection<Polygon>,
) => {
  switch (zoneType) {
    case ZoneZoneType.Type1:
    case ZoneZoneType.Type2:
      return zone1.zoneGeojsonFactory.exportZoneEdition(zone);
    case ZoneZoneType.Type3:
      return zone2.zoneGeojsonFactory.exportZoneEdition(zone);
    case ZoneZoneType.Type4:
      return zone3.zoneGeojsonFactory.exportZoneEdition(zone);
    default:
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions
      throw new Error(`Unknown zone type ${zoneType ?? '[undefined]'}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does this question depend on "geojson"? If so then you should probably tag it as such; if not, please [edit] to remove the apparent dependency of your code example.  Ideally it should be a self-contained [mre] that other people can just paste into their own IDEs and immediately get to work on the issue, without unrelated problems like missing types and values.

Comment: This is another case of "dependent-type-like" functions, where the output type depends on the specific type of the parameter. See [TS #33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).

Comment: Not sure if this is strictly a duplicate, but closely related recent question: [Typescript define function args and return value based on arg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76325719/15261914).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some specific case of [return type based on parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter)

Applied to your case :

```
type ObjectType<T> = 
  T extends ZoneZoneType.Type1 ? Zone1 :
  T extends ZoneZoneType.Type2 ? Zone1 :
  T extends ZoneZoneType.Type3 ? Zone2 :
  T extends ZoneZoneType.Type4 ? Zone3 :
never;
```

```js
export const exportZoneEditionGeojson = <T extends ZoneZoneType>(
  zoneType: T,
  zoneEditionGeojson: FeatureCollection<Polygon>,
): ObjectType<T> => {
  switch (zoneType) {
    case ZoneZoneType.Type1:
    case ZoneZoneType.Type2:
      return zone1.zoneGeojsonFactory
        .exportZoneEdition(zoneEditionGeojson) as ObjectType<T>;
    case ZoneZoneType.Type3:
      return zone2.zoneGeojsonFactory
        .exportZoneEdition(zoneEditionGeojson) as ObjectType<T>;
    case ZoneZoneType.Type4:
      return zone3.zoneGeojsonFactory
        .exportZoneEdition(zoneEditionGeojson) as ObjectType<T>;
    default:
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions
      throw new Error(`Unknown zone type ${zoneType}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: I could even be more dynamic by having this :
`type ObjectType <T> = T extends ZoneZoneType ? Extract<Zone, { zone_type: T }>['zone'] : never;`

Where zone has a `zone_type~ attribute that is equals to T. And them taking the zone attribute for the return type.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could use a map of inputs to output types, and a function overload.

I have added a definition for `ZoneZoneType` and the `zoneX` functions and then trimmed your code down to a Minimal Reproducible Example. Although, for this, even the second parameter is actually unnecessary.

```js
enum ZoneZoneType {
  Type1,
  Type2,
  Type3,
  Type4,
}

const zone1 = (input: string) => "zone1" as const;
const zone2 = (input: string) => "zone2" as const;
const zone3 = (input: string) => "zone3" as const;

type ResultMap = {
  [ZoneZoneType.Type1]: ReturnType<typeof zone1>;
  [ZoneZoneType.Type2]: ReturnType<typeof zone1>;
  [ZoneZoneType.Type3]: ReturnType<typeof zone2>;
  [ZoneZoneType.Type4]: ReturnType<typeof zone3>;
};

export function exportZone<T extends ZoneZoneType>(
  zoneType: T,
  zone: string
): ResultMap[T];
export function exportZone(zoneType: ZoneZoneType, zone: string) {
  switch (zoneType) {
    case ZoneZoneType.Type1:
    case ZoneZoneType.Type2:
      return zone1(zone);
    case ZoneZoneType.Type3:
      return zone2(zone);
    case ZoneZoneType.Type4:
      return zone3(zone);
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown zone type ${zoneType ?? "[undefined]"}`);
  }
}

const res1 = exportZone(ZoneZoneType.Type1, "foo");
//     ^? const res1: "zone1"
const res2 = exportZone(ZoneZoneType.Type2, "foo");
//     ^? const res2: "zone1"
const res3 = exportZone(ZoneZoneType.Type3, "foo");
//     ^? const res3: "zone2"
const res4 = exportZone(ZoneZoneType.Type4, "foo");
//     ^? const res4: "zone3"
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wO5vdm)

The function implementation is as you had. However, the signature the caller sees has the return type determined from the input, by indexing into the new `ResultMap` type.

This does not enforce actually returning the specified type, so it's up to you to ensure that the map and the returns are correct.
The answer by @Neiluj uses type assertions on the returns, so it is also unsafe.
Pick what works for your case.

[Overloads are unsafe in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76377198/15261914), so do be careful on your quest... :)

The advantages I see over the implementation using conditional types:

- the simpler syntax of the mapping type;
- record-based mapping types work better than conditional types in more complex scenarios;
- ease of switching to utilizing the "dependent-type-like functions" feature, should it be implemented.

Someone like @jcalz will likely be able to comment further on the differences.

See [TS #33014 ("Suggestion for Dependent-Type-Like Functions: Conservative Narrowing of Generic Indexed Access Result Type")](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for the request to add proper support for this.
See [@jcalz's answer to "TypeScript generics work when you call it but not in the function body?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73675625/15261914) for more info on workarounds for the general problem of defining parameters using generic type parameters.