# Typescript circular function reference

Tags: typescript, recursion, functional-programming

This function is actually quite simple, it either returns a function or a string depending on a inner function parameter.

```
function strBuilder(str: string) {
  return function next(str2?: string) {
    if(typeof str2 === "string") {
      return strBuilder(str + str2)
    } else {
      return str
    }
  }
}
```

However there is a type error when this expression is executed

```
strBuilder("Hello, ")("World")()
```

I would like to know how to properly annotate this function so that the type error is removed since inferencing is not working so nicely.

This type is something that I have in mind but I can not find a way to tell the function to be of that specific type.

```
type StringBuilder<S extends string> = (
  str: S
) => (str2?: S) => S extends string ? ReturnType<StringBuilder<S>> : string
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Here is the playground link which demonstrates the issue https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwEIFdEBsAmE8APDFBAB7ATJ4DOUtCKqAfFALxQAUAUFAwgBcsHgEoObLo3gAmAPzCY49m1IUqNetOZQ5UAEoRgmeMgAq4CCSZosuAsRgs2w7Wh48AZpmQBjYIgA9sgC8Hb4hFJCocziAN58UPBGJiHefgHBUMjqUbIKMWjxifyInlygkIGeoTIc7JwARG6ojcX8HUkppqHhDnlQANS1oiVQAL5kOLTQCZ38ycY90mPjiWtrPNJ9kY0AEhA4OIEANFBtXI0A6oHw+BejQA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest approach here is to express the return type of `strBuilder()` as an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) type:

```
interface StringBuilder {
  (str: string): StringBuilder;
  (): string;
}

function strBuilder(str: string): StringBuilder {
  return function next(str2?: string) {
    if (typeof str2 === "string") {
      return strBuilder(str + str2)
    } else {
      return str
    }
  } as StringBuilder // <-- assert
}
```

We need an [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) there because the compiler can't accurately verify that function implementations conform to overloaded call signatures (see [How to correctly overload functions in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76376494/2887218) ).

Anyway the above compiles and results in the desired call behavior:

```
const str = strBuilder("Hello, ")("World")();
console.log(str.toUpperCase())
```

---

You *could* write it as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), but that's more complicated and isn't necessarily more desirable (it really depends on use cases):

```
interface StringBuilder {
  <S extends string | undefined = undefined>(str?: S):
     S extends string ? StringBuilder : string;
}
```

That's similar to your version, except I'm just representing the return type directly (so as not to use [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) and so as not to worry about using the same `S` inside the original function and inside the returned function, which is not what you want) and I'm giving a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `S` in the case when someone calls the function with no argument (otherwise it would fall back to `string | undefined` which isn't useful).

You still need a type assertion inside the body of `strBuilder()` because the compiler also cannot accurately verify that function implementations conform to generic conditional return types; see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  So it's not like you gain or lose anything in terms of type safety here.

Anyway it behaves the same for the above example:

```
const str = strBuilder("Hello, ")("World")();
console.log(str.toUpperCase())
```

I'd probably stick with overloads unless you run into some specific trouble with it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5AbhATgGwPYgBMkBvAKCSQEtgAXLAMwWQGUbNqBzAIQFdLsCWEuQpIAFFDYAuJJPbAOAShmt53PgKwBuERTHLZbTjooBfUiPo9g8GpVzBDmXv0GYJ0p5wOrOLzZjCokiYEDQ8mI5WNnYOSMAQAB40HpgATAD8MnLeQcFU9OI0AJ4wELiFcmlIALx1SABEOQoNinn5IWERjnL+bqlIANROaYq6oqZIENhQyGQdFKHhkU7jZuOTIFBIvgp9WCLmIvAOkk61TvvuDQAS03gANI2KYg0A6rg4BK36JkgnwCguGwEAAdHgOKlQTRcABVGBlTAAYS2EH0YxEvQ0-QaGR+AFkQDQABagzAgYAEXBgfRIAA8SAADKCAKxIDKNEAAI3gDSQMmsgno1AgBEUWiQAHpJVNMJhPqQjqBILAmEgAOIQBLseBIhwESixUDYPLUOiYRiIHZGPbYoTzUR05hTZJagjbZocJAAHyQgogwoSRBqfspAZFBAAfKksjtlGsdi66JSPTavRzdupXEJsmm-kcKNFbPYemwrqlc2ofGmru1OssotZi3EEslUplK7kHcFKIUxCUyhURrV6k006068Elt1Lnb3HIhiMxh1JtNZpPRNOVnIE+ZgpttpmrocLBQAWcFyGsdnrndsI9nq8Pl8fuLjqdgWCIVCYfDESjZnRCwjiAA)

Comment: Your solution is easy enough to understand and elegant. 

Its a shame we have to use assertion to help the complier though. I will invest some time to fully understand why is that needed.

Anyhow, thank you. I appreciate your help and I will mark this one as solved.